# odbc apps script

Tags: odbc, google-apps-script

We have a core application that allows for ODBC connections. Currently I use MS Excel or Access to create reports. Many times per week I print them to .PDFs and email them to managers (not all managers have access to our core application). We have Google Apps and I was wondering if anyone had any experience connecting ODBC with GAS. I like to think my process could be better automated.

I also have databases that I have made available to users through Excel for dynamic reporting. I was wondering if I could migrate that to the GAS environment, also.

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you looking to keep the database private behind your firewall or is it webfacing?

Answer (score 0):

You could use JDBC to connect to the underlying database and then create your reports and other data manipulation in GAS.

See link for documentation\examples: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/jdbc